# Getiing an error when trying to store user email and other details in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a registration form to get the details of the user. But when the user enters the details it gives this error:

> INSERT INTO players(first_name, last_name, username, email, password)
>   VALUES (John, Doe, john.doe, john.doe@yahoo.com, doe)
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@yahoo.com,
>   aman)' at line 1
>
> Thank you for registering!

This is my PHP code for the form:

```
<?php
     $servername="localhost";
     $dbname="users";
     $username="root";
     $password="pass";
     try {

          $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
          $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
         $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
         $username = $_POST["username"];

         $email = $_POST["email"];
         $pwd = $_POST["password"];
    $sql="INSERT INTO players(first_name, last_name, username, email, password) VALUES ($first_name, $last_name, $username, $email, $pwd)";
         $dbh->exec($sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
           echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

    echo "<p>Thank you for registering!</p>";

?>
```

I did try & catch to catch the error as without that it was showing

> Thank you for registering!

and data wasn't stored in the database.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the code with PDO's Prepared statement:

```
<?php
     $servername="localhost";
     $dbname="users";
     $username="root";
     $password="pass";
     try {

          $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
          $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
         $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
         $username = $_POST["username"];

         $email = $_POST["email"];
         $pwd = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO players(first_name, last_name, username, email, password) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :pwd)";
    $statement->execute(array(':first_name' => $first_name, ':last_name' => $last_name, ':username' => $username, ':email' => $email, ':pwd' => $pwd));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
           echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

    echo "<p>Thank you for registering!</p>";

?>
```

Getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in
>   public_html\php\reg.php on line 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you should use quotes around the values. Ideally, you should use PDO's prepared statements instead, they have the benefit of automatically escaping values and being inherently more secure as well as having speed and other advantages.

```
$statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO players(first_name, last_name, username, email, password) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :pwd)");
$statement->execute(array(':first_name' => $first_name, ':last_name' => $last_name, ':username' => $username, ':email' => $email, ':pwd' => $pwd));
```

Also makes your query easier to read, checkout PHP's [PDO docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Comment: So if I want to convert my code to PDO's Prepared statement how will do that? Can you edit my code and give me a brief idea on how its done. I had tried it before but was unsuccessful.

Comment: The code I gave should work for your script, replace your $sql=..and $dbh->exec() line with these two statements.

Comment: Getting this error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in public_html\php\reg.php on line 16**

Comment: Had an extra quote, `$statement->execute(array(':first_name' => $first_name, ':last_name' => $last_name, ':username' => $username, ':email' => $email, ':pwd' => $pwd));`

Comment: that I resolved but i am getting this error after removing that.

Comment: Error resolved. There was one missing ')': `$statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO players(first_name, last_name, username, email, password) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :pwd)");`

Comment: Perhaps you're having an extra semi-colon somewhere, see resolving parse errors. What is your code?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are inserting a string into your query you must wrap it with quotes:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO players(first_name, last_name, username, email, password) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$username', '$email', '$pwd')";
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to wrap your variable with single quotes

```
$sql="INSERT INTO players(first_name, last_name, username, email, password) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$username', '$email', '$pwd')";
```

Comment: So MySQL has a problem with @ symbol in email?

Comment: No, when not quoting the query ends up being INSERT INTO players(...) VALUES (John, Doe, john@yourmail.com....), as you can see this is invalid SQL since strings in MySQL needs to be wrapped around quotes in order to be valid like INSERT INTO...VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@....'), if it didn't throw an error at @ it would throw at John since it would treat it as a column name instead of a string value.